# Track Modification History in Filemaker Databases

Tags: filemaker

Is there a way to store all timestamps and details of modifications of fields in a table automatically in Filemaker Pro 13? ie is there an easy option somewhere that Filemaker provides, or must I do this programmatically / manually?

Comment: You must implement this yourself. There are tools you can use for this, though. Search the web for "filemaker audit log".

Answer (score 1):

Ray Cologon, PhD and allround FileMaker superstar, wrote a custom function that works well for us.  It is free to use, but you must have a copy of FileMaker Pro Advanced to install the custom function.

http://www.nightwing.com.au/FileMaker/demosX/demoX01.html

Answer (score 1):

FileMaker does not provide a ready-to-go method of audit logging.  However, there are a few decent options.  Linear Blue provides [fmDataGuard](http://syncdek.com/fmdataguard/) and [SyncDek](http://syncdek.com/syncdek/) just for this purpose, and does a very nice job.  (SyncDek is great for [and requires] FileMaker Server; fmDataguard is great for standalone databases and small server deployments.)

Nightwing's solution is clever and hooks up very similarly to fmDataGuard, but I think fmDataGuard is more robust.

All of these audit logging solutions have a critical limitation.  You cannot log deletions as a [Full Access] user.  If this is critical for your application, SyncDek is the only solution that offers a work-around in the latest versions: record change polling.

There is a final possibility that might be worth considering for some applications.  Databases like MySQL have audit log plugins without the permissions limitations of FileMaker.  You can connect FileMaker to one or more MySQL databases and use their tables more-or-less like native FileMaker tables.  With the MySQL audit log plugin, you can get your audit logging and use FileMaker for your UI.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this programmatically. But with the help of `MBS Plugin` you can achieve this easily.

Here is the documentation [link](https://www.mbsplugins.eu/component_Audit.shtml)

Example :

```
MBS( "Audit.Changed"; timestamp; TableName { ; FieldsToIgnore } )
```