# Audit Trails for Adding/Modifying Fields, Tables, Layouts, Scripts in Filemaker 13

Tags: filemaker, audit, audit-trail, audit-logging

Is there a way to implement audit trails eg. by scripting or 3rd-party plugin that track Adding Fields, Modifying Field Types, Adding Tables, Adding Layouts etc. in Filemaker 13, whichever the version - Prop, Advanced, or Server etc.?

Comment: Does this (http://www.fmdiff.com/) help?

Answer (score 0):

In FileMaker, each of those things are grouped under the term "schema".  There aren't great first-party solutions to this.  You can't really track who modified what.  However, you can track changes.  I can recommend three ways.

First, [FMDiff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26959521/track-modification-history-in-filemaker-databases) will allow you to compare two FileMaker database files and see the schema differences.  It's pretty handy, and I use it in automated backups.

Second, if you don't want to use a third-party product like FMDiff, you can generate a DDR (Database Design Report) in FileMaker Advanced.  This is outputs every field, script, calculation, database field, table, table occurrence, relationship, and layout object in the database.  It's kinda tricky, but you can run a diff between the DDR in two different databases.

Third, there's [BaseElements](https://www.goya.com.au/baseelements).  This is a third-party database for studying DDRs.  You can use it for manually comparing two databases, and if you're so-inclined you might be able to script it display your comparisons for you.